# Using cron jobs within Hyperledger Fabric Chaincode

Tags: cron, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am attempting to setup a cron job to run on a 24 hour interval within my chaincode.  I am trying to use the following library to set up the scheduler: https://github.com/jasonlvhit/gocron.  If I run this outside of Fabric in a standalone go file it runs as it should.  But running it on a deployed chaincode it is not setting up a new scheduled task.  Is there something in Fabric that is preventing this library from working within the chaincode?  If that is the case, can you recommend another solution that would work with Fabric.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work. But I think you shouldn't do this because your chaincode would become nondeterministic/nonreproducible. I think the scheduler should be separate from the chaincode and execute it externally.

Comment: Yes I understand that it is not ideal but this is what was requested for it to do.  I would like to know why it does not work within Fabric though.  The scheduled task even if separate from the chaincode will still need to have the ability to access the chaincode and update the states that reside on the ledger. Any thoughts on how this could be done?

Comment: @JMO I think you can call the rest api or communicate with the network with composer-sdk and perform the operation.