# Invoke Chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am reading about chaincode in hyperledger fabric for my project. I have a doubt on 
How to invoke chaincode automatically based on events like time. If so, are any working examples available.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you looked to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42353060/using-cron-jobs-within-hyperledger-fabric-chaincode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot invoke transactions automatically without a client. If you look at the transaction flow of Hyperledger Fabric, the client has a lot of responsibilities signing the transactions, like collecting the endorsement, optionally filtering out the proposal responses (bad ones) and sending it for ordering. So, you cannot replace all this logic in the chaincode layer which is essentially responsible for endorsement.

You have to do this invocation based on events like time with the help of the client whose rules you are supposed to define.

So, best way would be put some sort of authorization logic on the chaincode function you want to invoke at regular intervals of time and use a client and a user's certificate to call the functions on the chaincode using some **cron** mechanism.

Reference to Authorization in Chaincode:

Summary Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTW9QVO28l0

Chaincode Reference: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.2/chaincode/abac/go

Documentation: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GP5tcN0oK9Zewed9h5pLiM2BowWPhtgFUGXEDKjeGGo/edit